# Kaminari: undefined method `total_pages' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

Using Rails & Kaminari gem, I am getting the below error when I render my view:

> undefined method `total_pages' for #Array:0x007faa486583e0

controller:

```
def index
    @user = current_shop.users.new
    @users = current_shop.active_users   ### This returns an array
    Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(10)
 end
```

view:

```
     <tbody>
       <%= paginate @users %>

        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <%= render 'user_table_row', :user=> user %>
       <% end %>

     </tbody>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

I think you have to assign

```
@users = Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

in your controller.

Comment: i am facing above issue even after adding this i'm having the same issue please help me in it

Comment: For me it didn't work without passing the `total_count` to `paginate_array`. Check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523671/kaminari-paginate-array-argumenterror-wrong-number-of-arguments-2-for-1#answer-33524108)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @users = current_shop.active_users.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Do it on the `ActiveRecord::Collection`

Comment: current_shop.active_users  is an array.  (active_users is a shop method to using .where(user_status: active) ). That's why I was using Kaminari.paginate_array

Comment: It's an active record collection, not an array.  So you're better off just letting kaminari add scopes to that.

Comment: current_shop.users is a collection. I have a method:  "def active_users
    users.where(status: "active").reverse
  end"  which returns an array. I want to paginate that array (current_shop.active_users)

Comment: I imagine it'd be quicker to do the ordering in the db query. But I see nothing wrong in what you've done with having an array so I'd suggest raising an issue in the kaminari repo