# Kaminari.paginate_array ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am using a rails application with the `kaminari` gem and I have a common array that I am trying to page using the paginate_array method but I am getting a **ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)** exception. Here is the code:

```
def index    

    page = params[:page] || 1
    items = ClientReports.search(params[:search], sort_column, sort_direction)
    @clients =  Kaminari.paginate_array(items, total_count: items.count).page(page)

    respond_with(@clients)

  end
```

The line: `Kaminari.paginate_array(items, total_count: items.count).page(page)` is the one throwing the error. Why is this a problem? From what I can see the [docs](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) show this should be ok.

Comment: Try `@clients =  Kaminari.paginate_array([items], total_count: items.count).page(page)`

Comment: yep, that's it. Submit this as an answer please. Strange that I need to specify the total_count though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

From the [**docs**](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari),

> You can specify the total_count value through options Hash.

***Example***

```
@paginatable_array = Kaminari.paginate_array([], total_count: 145).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

So in your case it should be

```
@clients = Kaminari.paginate_array([items], total_count: items.count).page(page)
```

Comment: 2 things, 1) the docs only tell you can specify it the array has a count different than items.count which is not the case here. 2) since items is already an array, [items] would cause problems. Thanks though.